# Swift Generic with type first known at runtime

Tags: swift, generics, runtime

i have a question about swift and generics. What I try to do is to get an Object with an generic type. But I first know the type at runtime. But to get to the point fast.

**New edited block:**

Maybe I can do it with the class name? I have a class name as a string. I got it via a Mirror. Can I create a generic instance with that classname in an string?

```
let classname: String = "ClassA"
let firstA: a<classname> = a<classname>()
//            ^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^
//            what to put here???
```

**New edited block end:**

I have two classes with generic types:

This is a protocol my type has to implement:

```
protocol ToImplement {
    func getTypeForKey(key: String) -> NSObject.Type
}
```

This is the class I use for my first Generic Type:

```
class MyClass: ToImplement {
    func getTypeForKey(key: String) -> NSObject.Type {
        if key == "key1" {
            return UIView.self
        } 
        else {
            return UIButton.self
        }
    }
}
```

this is my first Class with an generic type:

```
class a<T:ToImplement> {
    func doSomethingWith(obj: T) -> T {

        // the next part usually runs in an iteration and there can be
        // a lot of different types from the getTypeForKey and the number
        // of types is not known

        let type = obj.getTypeForKey("key1")
        let newA: a<type> = a<type>()       // how could I do this? To create a type I do not know at the moment because it is a return value of the Object obj?
        //          ^^^^      ^^^^
        //          what to put here???


        return obj
    }
}
```

and that is how I would use it:

```
let mycls: MyClass = MyClass()
let firstA: a<MyClass> = a<MyClass>()
firstA.doSomethingWith(mycls)
```

Now my question is: Can I create an instance of class a with a generic type I get as a return value of a function? Is that even possible?

If that is not possible, how could I create an instance with an generic type out of an other instance. Something like:

```
let someA: a<instance.type> = a<instance.type>()
```

Thank you for your help!

regards

Artur

Answer (score 1):

```
let type = obj.getType
```

OK, so `type` is a `NSObject.Type`. Since NSObject provides `init()`, you can instantiate this type with

```
let obj = type.init()  // obj is a NSObject (or subclass)
return obj
```

Of course, this will fail at runtime if the actual type returned by `getType()` doesn't implement `init()`.

Another option is to use an associated type:

```
protocol ToImplement {
    typealias ObjType: NSObject
}
```

Then you can use it as a generic constraint:

```
func makeAnObject<T: ToImplement>(obj: T) -> T.ObjType {
    return T.ObjType()
}
```

This gives basically the same result.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I think that is not what I need. Imagine I have a classes named Car, Bike and House. they implement the `ToImplement` protocol. My MyClass gives one of this types like Car, Bike, House or even itself (MyClass) back. Now I want to make a new instance of a with exactly the type that was given back, but I don´t know it at this time. maybe something like `let newA = a<obj.getTypeForKey("key1")>()`. I know this is not correct but its exactly what I try to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently. The way to do what you're asking seems to be to list every type that is known and instantiate the generic class concretely.

```
if type(of:instance) == MyClass.self {
    let someA = a<MyClass>()
} // more blocks for other concrete implementations
```